# Write code on iPad, offline

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, ios

I want to write code on my iPad, with the possibility to do it offline and to download the files later on my computer (MacBook Pro), for instance via iTunes.

- I am right now coding in Java.
- Offline compiling is not my priority now.
- Of course if there exists an app which can execute Java (or other languages, Swift, Python, Objective-C, etc.) it is a plus.

I am looking for tools that don't need jailbreak.

Comment: I've tried to edit this a bit - throwing in all the languages seems you want an IDE and not an editor? also - Apple's notes will sync to your Mac without any setup needed other than iCloud - if you focused on what you need past that function - it might get better answers than the hundreds of text editors that exist already.

Answer (score 1):

the best app I ever used: **Textastic**. It costs about 7 USD/EUR and it is one of the most sophisticated apps I know.
I am a web and app developer and I like to use it with SFTP connection support and Dropbox combination ...

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textastic-code-editor-6/id1049254261?mt=8

https://www.textasticapp.com

Comment: Does it have an offline mode with which you can still manage multiple files ?

Comment: Sure, absolutely. There is a local storage folder and after editing you can upload your files on the server to their remote location. It remembers, where edited files where downloaded from.

Comment: So you only download multiple files in the same local app folder on your device. And when uploading back to server, it automatically sends them to original location folder and you don't have to select the remote path ike in the oldschool commander way

Comment: Nice. Actually I don't need to upload, I just want to type code (Java).

Comment: I bought the app in 2012 and as I am responsible for many live websites at work and sometimes need to fix something, this is perfect application. They made it really sophisticated, let me know what you think after you decide to buy it. I have never found better app for this. I used it more frequently on iPhone than on iPad, even the iPad version is better to deal with such count of features it servers.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded [Buffer editor](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/buffer-editor-code-editor/id502633252?mt=8). 
It is cheaper than [Textastic](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textastic-code-editor-7/id1049254261?mt=8), that's why I chose it. 
So far, I am happy with my choice.

http://buffereditor.com